# Spinner loader in not loading in IE but it is loading in chrome

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am writing code for spinner loader. but it is not loading in IE browser.

```
.loaderActive {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.loaderActive:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you please put you code using `snippet `

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IE you are using?. Because SVG not supported below IE11 version. You can set meta tag to edge like this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

to support svg in IE.